# Generalization of stationary points to stationary lines (valleys)?

Tags: real-analysis

For suitably smooth functions $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the concept of stationary points, in particular local minima, can as easily be mathematically defined as it is intuitively understood visually.

Now, visually, one can also often easily identify valleys within functions. Think for example of a part of a waterslide.

The functions $f(x,y) = x^2 + (y/c)^2$, $|c| > 1$ for instance have a stationary point at the origin, and a valley along the y-axis. So we might consider every point $(0,y)$ as part of a stationary curve. However, despite the ease of the intuition, I do not know a mathematical definition that would fit in a more general case.

Do you know of any such generalization and if so, how to determine such?

*Naively, one might first think that only one component of the gradient needs to vanish, but subject to rotation, this is true for every point of a smooth function.*

---

**Edit (due to discussions below):**

As demonstrated below, two approaches on my side to more narrowly define what I think I am searching for have somewhat failed. Ironically, I can not give an objective answer why I feel so, as such an objective answer remains my question. I am putting these here to separate them from the original question.

*Faulty physical motivation:*

Physically, while a locally minimal point can be thought of as a ball remaining still on a surface, a valley might be where every part of a chain remains still (or while sliding down, follows a one-dimensional track). One may translate the latter into a rigorous mathematical property, but it seems there should be something easier and local.

*Faulty mathematical definition:*

A stationary curve (in two dimensions) of $f(x,y)$ may be defined as any path $p: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that fulfills the following property: there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $0 < \varepsilon < \delta$ and every open interval $I \subset (0,1)$, there is no path $p_{\varepsilon}: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus p(I)$ for which $f(p_{\varepsilon}(s)) < f(p(s))$ and $\|p_{\varepsilon}(s) - p(s)\| < \varepsilon$ for all $s \in I$.

Comment: A question to clarify what you're looking for: Why do you not see/wish to include the x-axis as a stationary curve for the function you used as an example?

Comment: To add onto my previous comment, it seems that the condition which you're looking for is that the curve is tangent to the gradient of $f$.

Comment: What you describe are the parts of the function where $f$ has constant values. This is unfortunately not what I mean.

Comment: It sounds like you want negative-gradient integral curves that also extremize some condition involving second derivatives. Maybe integral curves whose initial condition is a direction of maximum curvature at a critical point, or integral curves that are always tangent to an eigenvector of the Hessian matrix? Then could check that solutions are accumulators for other integral curves, to verify the intuition of a waterslide (water always descends along gradient, and will accumulate to the "minimum curve" of the slide)

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$As noted in a comment by Yankl, a stationary curve can be defined as one with tangent in the direction of the gradient of $f$. So, a stationary curve can be given as a solution to the system
\begin{equation}
    \dot x=f_x,\quad \dot y=f_y
\end{equation}
of ODEs, where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.

We can further say that a stationary curve $C$ for $f$ is the bottom of a valley (BoV) if the second directional derivative of $f$ at any point on $C$ in the direction $(f_y,-f_x)$, orthogonal to the gradient, is $>0$. We can also say that a stationary curve $C$ for $f$ is the top of a ridge (ToR) if $C$ is the BoV for the function $-f$.

For instance, if $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, then the projections of the stationary curves onto the $xy$-plane are the hyperbolas $\{(x,y)\colon xy=c\}$ for real $c$. The parts $\{(x,y)\colon xy=c,y^2>x^2\}$ of these projections correspond to the BoV's, while the parts $\{(x,y)\colon xy=c,y^2<x^2\}$ of these rojections correspond to the ToR's.

These BoV's and ToR's for $c=-1/10$ are shown (in blue) in the picture below (two BoV's and two ToR's):

[image]

---

The OP has added the following:

> **Edit:** I think I may give a more proper mathematical definition thanks to the discussion below. It probably still lacks some additional care, and in particular, it does not answer how to obtain such practically.
>
> A stationary curve (in two dimensions) of $f(x,y)$ may be defined as any path $p: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that fulfills the following property: there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $0 < \varepsilon < \delta$ and every open interval $I \subset (0,1)$, there is no path $p_{\varepsilon}: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus p(I)$ for which $f(p_{\varepsilon}(s)) < f(p(s))$ and $\|p_{\varepsilon}(s) - p(s)\| < \varepsilon$ for all $s \in I$.

Well, if this is the definition of a stationary curve, then the OP's question has been answered. However, this definition is not good.

Indeed, let $f$ be the "slide" function given by the formula $f(x,y):=x^2+y$. Then apparently the OP (and everyone) would agree that the path $p$ given by the formula $p(s):=(0,s)$ corresponds to a stationary, bottom-of-a-valley curve for $f$; see a graph of $f$ together with the (red) stationary curve:

[image]

However, letting $p_\ep(s):=(\ep/2,s-\ep^2/2)$ for $\ep\in(0,1)$, we see that $p_\ep((0,1))\cap p((0,1))=\emptyset$, $f(p_\ep(s))<f(p(s))$ and $\|p_\ep(s)-p(s)\|<\ep$ for all $s\in(0,1)$, so that the path $p$ is not stationary in the sense of the highlighted definition.

Similarly to the first example in this answer, with $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, we can describe the stationary curves for $f(x,y):=x^2+y$: These are the curves whose projections onto the $xy$-plane are the "exponential" curves $\{(x,y)\colon x=ce^{2y}\}$ for real $c$. Each of these curves is the BoV in its entirety. The red curve in the latter picture corresponds to $c=0$, and the black curve there corresponds to $c=-1/20$.
Shown in the latter picture also is the (dashed) curve on the surface whose projection onto the $xy$-plane is the straight line orthogonal to the projection onto the $xy$-plane of the black stationary curve at the point with $y=3/5$; this dashed curve on the surface is orthogonal to the black BoV itself at the point on the surface with $y=3/5$ and $x=ce^{2y}$ (still with $c=-1/20$). Walking any distance along the dashed curve on the surface left or right away from the black BoV will increase the vertical coordinate of the walker (because here $f$ is convex). So, the black curve is truly the bottom of a valley.

---

Here is yet another example, now with all the stationary curves congruent to one another: Let $f(x,y):=
x + x^3/3 + y$. Then the projections of the stationary curves onto the $xy$-plane are given by equations $y=c + \arctan x$, where $c$ is any real number, so that the surface that is the graph of the function $f$ is the disjoint union of the family of stationary curves $L_c$ indexed by the real-valued parameter $c$. (Parts of these curves with $x>0$ are the BoV's and parts of these curves with $x<0$ are the ToR's.)
It follows that, for any real values $c_1$ and $c_2$ of the parameter $c$, the stationary curve $L_{c_2}$ is obtained from the stationary curve $L_{c_1}$ by the parallel translation $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y+c_2-c_1,z+c_2-c_1)$.
Therefore, here two different walkers walking with the same speed (say down) two different stationary lines (with different values of the parameter $c$) starting at the points of these two stationary lines with the same coordinate $x$ will have exactly the same experiences. So, there is no reason whatsoever to view any one of the stationary curves as special.

Here is a graph of this function $f$ together with the three (blue) stationary curves corresponding to $c\in\{-1,0,1\}$:

[image]

Comment: The second directional derivative orthogonal to the gradient was indeed something I considered. It may be that the curve I am looking for is contained in the set of curves you define, but my intuition tells me that the set is not yet what I am searching for. I think some physical chain would indeed slide along these curves (assuming zero inertia), but when fixing one point of such a chain, it would not stay on its curve, while only a chain of finite length would remain still when symmetrically placed within $x=0$. I would expect only a zero-set to be stationary curves in generic cases.

Comment: @SebastianK. : I don't understand your comment. In particular, what do you mean by "when fixing one point of such a chain, it would not stay on its curve"? What do you mean by "fixing"? What do you mean by $it"? What do you mean by "stay"?

Comment: What maybe comes closer is that not only the second derivatives along straight lines orthogonal to the gradient must be larger than zero, but that this also holds true along any circle which tangent is orthogonal to the gradient at the point where it intersects the supposed stationary curve. This seems to be more in line with the physical interpretation, though I have not rigorously checked this.

Comment: I meant this quite literally in a physical sense. Take a real saddle (with exactly the surface of $f$), place a metal chain on it, put your finger onto one of its segments and see what happens. I hope this is a bit clearer. Well, obviously, the problem is that I can not give you a clear mathematical definition.

Comment: @SebastianK. : These curves will satisfy this physical condition. Put your finger infinitesimally close to the lowest end of the chain. To minimize the potential energy, the lowest segment of the chain below you finger will go in the direction on the surface whose projection onto the $xy$-plane will be opposite to the direction of the gradient of $f$ at the point that is the projection of your finger onto the $xy$-plane. Moving your finger continuously up along the chain, you will get the desired result.

Comment: Your argument sounds quite reasonable so far, but it may be that the physical metaphor only goes that far. When I take a finite path $p|_{[0,1]}$ within one of the BoV you describe, could I not move that path continuously to lower valued points without changing the length of the path? (measured through the projection of the path onto the xy plane)

Comment: @SebastianK. : No, such a move is impossible. If now you don't want to appeal to physics after all, replace, in my argument above, "minimize the potential energy" to "move [the lowest infinitesimal segment] to the lowest possible position".

Comment: I am not sure if this can be true. As far as I can see, the BoV above span a family of functions are a infinitely close to each other. So it should be possible to move between different constants c. Sorry if my description is not clear. It is an intuition I try to catch that is yet difficult to put into words. But this discussion already helped me a lot. I will maybe try to put it into a proper definition tomorrow.

Comment: @SebastianK. : "So it should be possible to move between different constants c". No. Just revisit my reasoning. Alternatively, to help your intuition, trajectories of falling bodies may be however close to another, but of course, such a falling body cannot escape its trajectory (unless some external work on it is done).

Comment: I have tried to define what I had in mind more properly in an edit of my original post. This should clarify my intentions.

Comment: @SebastianK. : The ideas that you presented contradict one another, as it has now been explained at the end of my answer. I think it is now time to finalize this matter.

Comment: You are right with your first argument. The mathematical definition is not strictly what I am searching for, though I explicitly mentioned that it might need more work. I do however not support the argument that the presented idea contradict each other. The problem I am obviously having is that I can not put my supposed intuition into a strict definition. Thus arguing against these strict definitions or giving examples where these definitions yield undesired outcomes does unfortunately not yield a satisfactory answer. My question still remains, though certainly my intuition may be fooling me.

Comment: @SebastianK. : My answer corresponds to what you are now saying is "Faulty physical motivation". Why faulty?

Comment: @SebastianK. : Indeed, the BoV (bottom of a valley) as defined in my answer has the following property: if you move by any small enough distance from any point on such a path exactly left or exactly right (**orthogonally to the path** at that point on it), then your vertical coordinate will only increase. This is precisely what a BoV should be. This definition also corresponds to what you described by means of putting a finger on a chain. Therefore, I believe that my answer is correct and complete.

Comment: While BoV's seem to be the answer provided to the initial physical motivation, I think that it is not what I search for for the following reason. That the second directional derivation is larger than zero should, for a finite curve, also hold true when slightly moved to the left or right. Thus, if I am not mistaken, in the example $f(x,y) = x^2 + y$, multiple curves along the gradient flow other than in $(0,y)$ should fulfill the same condition.

Comment: It might be though that the answer is to only consider infinite curves, or curves ranging from one stationary point to another. This could exclude multiple curves in generic examples, but this might potentially require moderate time to look into, whereas I rather hoped that an answer might already be more common knowledge. This would also imply that local criteria are not sufficient to capture what I am searching for.

Comment: @SebastianK. : "That the second directional derivation is larger than zero should, for a finite curve, also hold true when slightly moved to the left or right." Here you missing the condition $\dot x=f_x,\ \dot y=f_y$, which means that the tangent vector to the curve is in the direction of the gradient of $f$, so that the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction normal to the curve is $0$ at any point of the curve.

Comment: Previous comment continued: If you move slightly left or right, then the latter condition will fail to hold, because the second directional derivative of $f$ in the direction normal to the curve is $>0$.

Comment: I was a bit unclear with the answer. I meant to for example shift the starting point $p(0)$ of a path $p: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a little bit, and then let a new path $\tilde{p}$ with $\tilde{p}(0) = p(0) + \epsilon$ continue along the gradient flow but starting at $\tilde{p}(0)$. Should this, for small enough $\epsilon$, not also fulfill the second derivative inequality?

Comment: @SebastianK. : Yes, of course. For instance, as was written in the answer, if $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, then the stationary curves are all hyperbolas $\{(x,y)\colon xy=c\}$ for real $c$. The parts $\{(x,y)\colon xy=c,y^2>x^2\}$ of these stationary curves are the BoV's (while the parts $\{(x,y)\colon xy=c,y^2<x^2\}$ of these stationary curves are the ToR's). For any two close values of $c$, the corresponding BoV's are close to one another. There is no one "preferred" BoV -- your steepest descent/ascent path depends on your starting point.

Comment: @SebastianK. : I have added a description of the BoV's for the slide function $f(x,y)=x^2+y$, and also added one such BoV to the corresponding picture. Even for such a simple/nice slide function, we have an infinite continuous family of stationary curves. Walking along any such curve, **locally** you will see the same kind of picture: your descent/ascent will be the steepest, and making any small enough step exactly to the right or exactly to the left of your path will increase your vertical coordinate.

Comment: @SebastianK. : To the second picture, I have also added a path normal to the black BoV for $f(x,y):=x^2+y$, with a corresponding comment.

Comment: As you can see, I have worked pretty to address all your questions. Do you have have a further response?

Comment: I do appreciate your investigation, yet the curve in red could and ought to have some more designated property than the neighboring black curve. I understand your arguments, but nevertheless, my original question remains.

Comment: @SebastianK. : Can you explain why? As I see it, the red curve is special only because (it is straight, and therefore) its projection onto the $xy$-plane is straight. For $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, there are also two special stationary lines that are straight, and therefore their projections onto the $xy$-plane are straight. However, it is easy to construct examples without such straight projections, and then there will no be no special stationary curves.

Comment: @SebastianK. : Also, what is your "original question", exactly? A question on MathOverflow should be such that it be clear what constitutes an answer to it, and what does not. I think you should agree that my definition adequately addresses what you referred to as a valley and also your intuition about holding a finger.

Comment: My original question is, as written above, if someone knows a mathematical concept that satisfies the supposed intuition. We apparently seem to disagree about the necessity of a clear answer. I have already up-voted your contribution as valuable, but while I do not expect a *yes* as answer to my question, I have reasons not to mark this contribution as solution. As this particular discussion has become unproductive in response to a meta-mathematical question, this is going to be my last input on it.

Comment: @SebastianK. : What is "the supposed intuition"? More recently, you had a "Faulty physical motivation" and a "Faulty mathematical definition". Prior to that, you  had a "valley" intutiion and a "finger" intuition, and those ones are satisfied by the answer -- right?

Comment: @SebastianK. : I have added an example where all the stationary curves are congruent to one another and hence none of them can possibly have any preference over the others. Hopefully, this can help. (I agree with you that this discussion has not been very productive -- but who is responsible for that, if you are not even saying what your "supposed intuition" is?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in the *acceleration* of integral curves of the gradient vector field (aka, "gradient flow curves").

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is at least $C^2$, with gradient $\nabla f$ and Hessian $\operatorname{H}f$.

If $\gamma$ is an integral curve for $\nabla f$, then for all $t$,
$$ \ddot{\gamma}(t) = \operatorname{H}f_{\gamma(t)} \dot{\gamma}(t) $$
This follows from $\nabla f_q \approx_{q\to p} \nabla f_p + \operatorname{H}f_p (q-p)$ applied to the fact that $\dot{\gamma} = \nabla f$.

Since $f\in C^2$, its Hessian is symmetric, so admits an eigenvalue decomposition. Say a **gradient flow curve of minimal acceleration** is a gradient flow curve $\gamma$ with $\dot{\gamma}$ always lying in a minimum-eigenvalue eigenspace of $\operatorname{H}f$. (This need not always happen.)

Reversing time, so $t\to -\infty$, gradient flow curves will tend toward minimal acceleration curves. Here is a quick qualitative argument: If $e_j, \lambda_j$ is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $\operatorname{H}f$ at point, write in coordinates $\dot{\gamma} = c_1v_1+\ldots +c_nv_n$. Now observe that $c_j(t - dt) \approx c_j(t) / (1 + dt \lambda_j)$, so the larger $\lambda_j$, the faster the component of $\dot{\gamma}$ in the direction of $v_j$ decays as $t\to -\infty$.

This tendency confirms the intuition of a waterslide: as water tumbles downhill (following exactly gradient descent), it accumulates toward a curve of minimal acceleration.

I would expect physicists have studied this concept as it is similar to the Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics. But I don't know the keywords to search.

### Examples

Just to check whether this concept tracks with the desired intuition, this section works through the examples shared by Iosif Pinelis above, plus one more to illustrate.

#### (A) $f(x,y) = x^2 + y$

The Hessian of $f$ has two eigenvalues, $2$ and $0$, with eigenspaces parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes respectively. For initial data $c_x, c_y$ the gradient flow curves have the form $ \gamma(t) = \big( c_x \exp(2t), t + c_y \big) $. Thus the minimum acceleration curve is the y-axis and as $t\to -\infty$ the gradient flow paths accumulate to the $y$-axis as expected.

#### (B) $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$

The Hessian of $f$ has two eigenvalues at each point, $2$ and $-2$, with eigenspaces parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes respectively. For initial data $c_x, c_y$ the gradient flow curves have the form
$ \gamma(t) = \big( c_x \exp(2t), c_y\exp(-2t) \big) $
and the two minimal acceleration gradient flow curves are the positive and negative y axes: exactly how we would expect water to flow off a saddle.

#### (C) $f(x,y) = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + y$

This example illustrates that curves of minimal acceleration need not exist. The Hessian of $f$ at $(x,y)$ has two eigenvalues, $2x$ and $0$, with eigenspaces parallel to the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis respectively.

The gradient flow curves have the form $\gamma(t) = \big( \tan(c_x + t), c_y + t \big)$. As $\dot{\gamma}(t) = \big(\sec^2(c_x + t), 1\big)$ we see that no gradient flow curves are ever tangent to an eigenspace of the Hessian. So there are no minimal acceleration gradient flow curves.

#### (D) $f(x,y) = \sin(x) + y$

Here's a picture of the graph of $f$:

[[image: graph of <span class=]$\sin(x)+y$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUEtj.gif)

Intuition is that the minimal acceleration gradient curves lie along the valleys of this slope. The gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f = \big( \cos(x), 1\big)$ and computing the Hessian of $f$ yields
$$ \operatorname{H}f = \begin{bmatrix} -\sin(x) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Gradient flow curves for initial data $c_x,c_y$ are
$ \gamma(t) = \big( 2\arctan(\tanh((t + c_x)/2), t + c_y \big)$, except for a degenerate family of paths moving at constant speed parallel to the $y$ axis when $x = \pi/2 + k\pi$ corresponding to the ridges and valleys.

The eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix are $-\sin(x), 0$ with eigenspaces parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively (away from $x$ a multiple of $2\pi$, in which case there is a single $0$-eigenspace). The only paths that are always tangent to an eigenspace are the degenerate paths $(c_x, t+c_y)$ when $c_x = \pi/2 + k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

When $k$ is odd these degenerate paths are gradient flow curves of minimal acceleration (Hessian eigenvalue $0$) and as expected the gradient flow accumulates to these paths as $t\to -\infty$.

As an aside: at $x = \pi/2 + k\pi$ ($k$ odd) the function $f$ is equal to example (A), the "waterslide," to second order (and scaling and addition of a constant). So it is no surprise that the gradient curves behave the same way.

To illustrate, here is a plot of the gradient flow of $f$ superimposed on a contourplot of $f$:
[[image: gradient streamplot of <span class=]$\sin(x)+y$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnlqe.png)